# Why if $f$ is a function and $x$ an element, what we write $f(x)$ is written $xf$ sometimes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

In the book [here](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmtrt/teaching/old_courses/Res_Math_Sci/Representations_and_Characters_of_Groups.pdf), if $G$ and $H$ are two group, the define the homomorphism \begin{align*}
\varphi:G&\longrightarrow H\\
g&\longmapsto g\varphi.
\end{align*}
In fact, if you see a little bit the book, all homomorphism are written like this (group, vector space, rings, modules...).This notation is so unused (and weird), I wonder why they use this notation. It should has a reason, and I wanted to know the positif/negatif arguments compare to the notation $\varphi (g)$ (or $\varphi g$ as it's commonly used too).

Comment: See the post [functions applied from the right](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187205/functions-applied-from-the-right).

Comment: The advantage is that the order is not transposed, so the function $\phi\psi$ takes $g$ to $g\phi\psi$ whereas with the usual notation it takes $g$ to $\psi(\phi(g))$

Comment: @almagest That's only if you think that $\phi \psi$ necessarily means $\phi$ then $\psi$. (It doesn't.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Well, it depends what you are used to. It is clearly a benefit if things are always in the same order. But the post notation has certainly dropped out of fashion because people are taught calculus before algebra and find it hard to make the change from $f(x)$ to $(x)f$

Comment: It's *Polish reverse notation*. It's used in several computer languages, among which `lisp` and `postscript`.